# Windows 10 Docker Network DNS doesn't work after reboot

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-network, docker-for-windows

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the current version of Windows Docker network or poor configuration and misunderstanding on my part, but I have the following setup:

- 2 Docker containers (built using the Microsoft/ASP.NET image as a base) running a .NET MVC application in each.
- 1 Docker container running SQL server (built using the Microsoft/mssql-server-windows image)

When I create all 3 containers everything works great, I can attach and ping all other the other containers using their names without any issue. The applications run and can communicate with each other as I hoped.

However, when I reboot my machine and start all the containers again they can no longer ping/communicate with each other using their names (using IP addresses is fine).

I've tried this on the default NAT network and also tried replacing the NAT network with my own custom NAT network.

To resolve the issue I have to run the force network disconnect command for each container as such:

```
docker network disconnect nat <containername> --force
```

And then I have to reconnect each container to the network before starting them up. All containers can then ping/communicate with each other using their names as well as their IP addresses.

FYI, this is a development environment but I was hoping to do something similar in Azure using a Windows Server 2016 VM, although I don't quite know what the best network configuration is for live production yet as I need to have multiple applications (in separate containers) on the same node accessed via their own subdomains.

Any help or guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, in part because this question was asked several months before any other example I've run into, but this sounds very similar to the problem described at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038.

Basically, there appears to be a problem introduced with the 1709 update to Windows 10 which results in a scenario where Hyper-V networking doesn't work the way it ought to.

There appear to be two common ways of working around this problem: Turning off "Fast Start" in the Control Panel => Power Options => System Settings, or restarting Docker for Windows and any containers after booting. I also thought I saw something on a Microsoft blog post indicating that the underlying problem has now been resolved and will be included in an update to Windows 10, but alas I can no longer find that information or the specific version number in which the problem was (theoretically) resolved. It may well be the delayed 1803 "Spring Creators Update" release.